# Best Graphics Library Java

Tags: java, graphics, 2d

I have to write a Java application that allows the user to create a visual representation of a binary tree. ie: add nodes to a canvas, drag them around, link them with a line, etc etc.

I managed to get a pretty basic app going with the standard Java Graphics2D and Swing, AWT - but I don't think its nearly powerful enough. The main problem I ran into was trying to render lines between the nodes (easy), and then update the line position when the nodes are dragged around (hard).

Anyway, I had a look at LWJGL as it seems quite powerful, but I'm worried its too powerful. I'd rather shy away from OpenGL if possible. Any recommendations?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The main problem I ran into was trying to render lines between the nodes (easy), and then update the line position when the nodes are dragged around (hard).

trashgod's [GraphPanel](https://sites.google.com/site/drjohnbmatthews/graphpanel) should give you some ideas.